# Can I use Babel to transpile to ES5 but keep import/export instead of commonjs?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules

I want to create an npm library that delivers modules using ES import/export instead of commonjs (like for example `lodash-es` does). If I'm not mistaken, the delivered code must be ES5 and has import/export.

I can't figure out how to configure Babel to do that. I expect that the option [`targets.esmodules`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsesmodules) should do the trick.

When I have the following code in `calc.js`:

```js
// calc.js
export function add (a, b) {
    const result = a + b
    return result
}
```

and babel configuration `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When running babel:

```
babel calc.js
```

The output is:

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.add = add;

function add(a, b) {
  var result = a + b;
  return result;
}
```

Which is commonjs (`exports.add`). The option `targets.esmodules` seems to have no effect. How can I get Babel to generate an es module (`export function add`)? Or am I misunderstanding the idea of delivering ES modules on npm?

Comment: "*If I'm not mistaken, the delivered code must be ES5 and has import/export.*" - you probably are mistaken there. Any environment that understands `import`/`export` does also understand all the other ES6 syntax, so this requirement is really weird.

Comment: Thanks. That was my assumption too, but I get quite some issues reported for [mathjs](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/1554). JS projects normally never transpile code from dependencies, only from the source of a project itself. So it gives issues when I publish a library that needs transpilation. 

Looking at [`redux`](https://unpkg.com/browse/redux@4.0.4/), the `es` folder contains es `import`/`export` and the code is transpiled ES5 (no `=>`, `const`, etc). Same with [`lodash-es`](https://unpkg.com/browse/lodash-es@4.17.15/). How to achieve that with Babel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like based on [the Rollup docs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module#wait-it-just-means-import-and-export--not-other-future-javascript-features) that you should indeed transpile a version that has only `import`/`export`, but has transpiled out all of the other non-ES5 syntax. The [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended) say something similar. This format assumes that your users are using tools like Rollup or Webpack, which natively support `import`/`export` statements, but then presumably transpile them to an ES5 compatible syntax without needing to run your library through Babel.

And it looks like Redux in particular pulls this off [by using the Rollup `format` option](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/14efbe1cccdca915b5bb9ff8ce22da4c4d5d6868/rollup.config.js#L8-L29) and then in their `.babelrc` file [they use the `"modules": false` option](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/14efbe1cccdca915b5bb9ff8ce22da4c4d5d6868/.babelrc.js#L12) to tell Babel not to transpile module statements. It's not clear to me how Lodash manages it, since looking over [their source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) I don't see any build scripts anywhere in the repo.

Comment: Yippie, that's indeed the missing link, thanks a ton Robert for figuring this out! I've a proof of concept working now with Babel config `{"presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }]]}`.